# Conda PackagesNotFoundError prevents installing/uninstalling packages?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have (what I thought to be) a stable conda environment (hold your laughter). In this environment, I've installed `numba` via `pip` (again, hold your laughter). I'd like to uninstall via `pip`, and re-install via `conda`.

I find this, after uninstalling via pip:

```
(tasso) ubuntu@ip-XXX:~/Work/ds_util/tasso$ conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - mkl==2018.0.3=intel_1
  - openmp==2018.0.3=intel_0
  - intel-openmp==2019.1=intel_144
  - zlib==1.2.11=5
  - libffi==3.2.1=11
```

All of the typical conda tricks don't work here: `conda install anaconda` gives the same list of missing packages. I would expect a package manager to, you know, manage these packages? Is this a `miniconda` thing?

More context:

```
(tasso) ubuntu@ip-XXX:~/Work/ds_util/tasso$ conda info

     active environment : tasso
    active env location : /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tasso
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /home/ubuntu/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.11 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.15.0-1016-aws ubuntu/18.04.1 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I'm frustrated by environments that seem to always be out of sync with conda, is this a common problem people deal with?

Comment: Perhaps "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)" might be worth a read, if you haven't already done so.  I'm guessing you're not getting out of this with anything less than recreating the env. Sorry.

Comment: I've recreated envs probably three times in the last month. Seriously looking for better alternatives now...